# Pass $ character to Gradle start scripts (Application plugin)

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a Gradle build script that uses the Application plugin, and I want to pass as JVM argument a string that contains the `$` character, but I can't because it always is converted to the `\$` sequence of characters...

Here is my configuration:

```
application {
    mainClass = 'example.Main'
    application.applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['-javaagent:$APP_HOME/lib/agent.jar']
}
```

But then in the start script I get:

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-javaagent:\$APP_HOME/lib/agent.jar"'
```

And because of that `\` it doesn't work, I need the value to be `-javaagent:$APP_HOME/lib/agent.jar`. All ways I tried get the same result (using interpolation, passing the $ as `\u0024`, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20968466/2123905) for a related question. The code in question is the following:

```
startScripts {
    doLast {
        unixScript.text = unixScript.text.replace('\\$APP_HOME', '\$APP_HOME') 
        //do something like this for Windows scripts if needed too
    }
}
```